# Excel VBA ListRows.Add adding data into cells, but not adding row to table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple VBA that adds a row to an Excel table - the first four columns have data entered by VBA, and the last four columns automatically copy a formula from the row above, as would normally happen when adding a row to a table. I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, but here it is anyway for reference:

```
Sub addAccountEmail()
    Dim ws1    As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trade")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    Dim tbl    As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws2.ListObjects("accountActivity")

    With tbl.ListRows.Add
        .Range(1) = Application.UserName
        .Range(2) = Date
        .Range(3) = Time
        .Range(4) = "Email"
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem I'm getting is that when the VBA is run, every now and then, data is added, but just as a normal Excel range, rather than adding a table row. The formulas also pull through but show as `#VALUE!`, as though someone has dragged up the range of the table to disclude the row. The screenshot below to demonstrate:

[image: Screenshot of table error]

I'm sure it's not my code because I've used the same method multiple times before without problems. It's a file saved in SharePoint, with multiple users running using it at the same time - could that potentially be the problem?

EDIT: formulas in order are `=IF(WEEKNUM([@Date])=WEEKNUM(TODAY()),1,"")`, `=IF(WEEKNUM([@Date])=WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1,1,"")`, `=IF(EOMONTH([@Date],0)=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),1,"")`, `=IF(AND([@Date]>=spec!$D$5,[@Date]<=spec!$D$6),1,"")`. I believe the reason an error is returned when the formula is outside of the table is because it's referring to a table column, i.e. `[@Date]`.

Comment: What are the formulae?

Comment: I've added the formulae to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me (Excel 2013). However, I find your enumerations of `Range(1)` etc rather odd. Perhaps your version of Excel thinks so, too. Please try this more conventional syntax.

```
Sub addAccountEmail()

    Dim ws1    As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trade")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    Dim tbl    As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws2.ListObjects("accountActivity")

    Dim tblRow As Range
    Set tblRow = tbl.ListRows.Add.Range
    With tblRow
        .Cells(1) = Application.UserName
        .Cells(2) = Date
        .Cells(3) = Time
        .Cells(4) = "Email"
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, I am on record at Rubberduck to oppose their idea that spreading Dim statements throughout the code  helps to make the latter more readable. Never heard so much nonsense before! The system presumes that each variable will only be used once. That is rarely the case. In every other case you may have to look up the declaration, and if that isn't at the top of the code you will have to search for it all over the place.

Comment: Thanks. I can try it, but my code normally works fine for me as well, and if Range was the problem, surely it would break every time? I'll make the change anyway and see if it sorts it.