# Insert values from array to cells in new row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listobject

I insert a new row (to Excel) and add data from an array into it. The array is smaller in length than the number of cells in a row.

Number of cells in single row: 12
Array: 9

The last 3 cells have formulas which automatically get copied when a new row is added, however the only way I can add new data is by overwriting these which comes up as #N/A.

The array amongst other things consists of data like this:

```
tempArray(j)=Array("=HYPERLINK([@Location]," & Chr(34) & files.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(i) & Chr(34) & ")",...,...,...,...)
```

I know if I have static unrelated formulas (non `@`) that I can do away with `ListRows.Add` which is what I was doing but now I need related formulas.

I have tried various things like:

```vb
With data.ListRows.Add

    'Set newRng = .Range.Range(.Range.Cells(1, 1), .Range.Cells(1, 9))

    .Range.Range(.Range.Cells(1, 1), .Range.Cells(1, 9)).Value2 = tempArray(i)
    .Range.Value2 = tempArray(i)
     
    'data.Range(data.Cells(lr + 1, 1), data.Cells(lr + 1, UBound(tempArray(i)) + 1)).Value = tempArray(i)
    
    lr = lr + 1
    
End With
```

I know this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726982) relates to something similar, but I want to apply it all in one go as opposed to one by one.

Comment: So, you try dropping the array content in a `ListObject` row. Is this understanding correct? If so, what kind of array is the one to drop its content? A 1D array type? A 2D? If 2D, does it contain more than a row? Then, based on what the last three cells " automatically get copied when a new row is added"? Is it done by an event?

Comment: when it gets applied it is a 1d array. So temp array is an array of arrays and then tempArray(i) is a 1d dimensional array. The last 3 cells have a column formula, something like =[@Name]&"_"&[@Location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the range of the listrow according to the size of your tempArray:

```
Dim lr as ListRow   'I prefer to use a single variable for readability reasons
With data
    Set lr = .ListRows.Add
    lr.Range.Resize(, UBound(tempArray) + 1).Value = tempArray
End With
```

Comment: This works! for my use case anyway. But if I needed to to pick a range in the middle, say cells 4-9 how would one go about doing that?

Comment: then you `offset` and `resize` --> `lr.Range.Offset(,4).resize(,6)`